# Do I need linux-libc-dev and libc6-dev?

Tags: kernel, package-management, 13.04, dependencies

I removed the stock 3.8.0-19-generic kernel (and meta packages for the stock ubuntu kernel) and installed the 3.9 mainline kernel, do I need these 2 packages or can I remove them?

```
~$ apt-cache policy linux-libc-dev
linux-libc-dev:
  Installed: 3.8.0-19.29
  Candidate: 3.8.0-19.30
  Version table:
     3.8.0-19.30 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.8.0-19.29 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
~$ apt-cache policy libc6-dev
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.17-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 2.17-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 2.17-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I completely removed (aka purged) all of these:
`linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic linux-headers-3.8.0-19`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need them to compile drivers by using DKMS (NVIDIA proprietary drivers do that). Otherwise, you're fine.

Comment: these packages are preinstalled, on both my laptop and desktop, my laptop has no proprietary drivers nor does it have virtualbox

Comment: Confirmed, removing this on my desktop would remove nvidia-313-updates as well

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need them, unless you are going to be compiling C.