# Removing left over kernel packages from previous kernel after hwe upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

I am using 16.04.2 and I made hwe upgrade(4.8) of kernel and xorg using:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

I have cleaned the previous kernel left overs as best as I could but I still see the following:

```
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                        4.4.0-64.85                                   amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-tools-4.4.0-64                        4.4.0-64.85                                   amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 4.4.0-64
ii  linux-tools-4.4.0-64-generic                4.4.0-64.85                                   amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 4.4.0-64
ii  linux-tools-common                          4.4.0-64.85                                   all          Linux kernel version specific tools for version 4.4.0
ii  linux-tools-virtual                         4.4.0.64.68                                   amd64        This package will always depend on the latest minimal generic kernel tools.
```

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/600702/616624) that these linux-tools packages are required by TLP program. I use TLP in its default mode. 
I [also read](https://askubuntu.com/a/290477/616624) `linux-libc-dev` package is required for compiling drivers like Nvidia.

So do I need to upgrade them to their hwe versions(4.8)? If yes, how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I do not think you really need the `virtual` tools. Do you have a `virtual` kernel image installed?

Comment: I don't know what virtual kernel image is. I don't know how that was installed.

Comment: Anyway you can upgrade it too. It is needed only for virtual kernels that are used in virtual machines. 99% you can safely delete this package if you are not in a VM.

Comment: Okay I used a virtual machine image from an operating systems course. It is probably because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `4.8` `linux-tools` by

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-tools-virtual-hwe-16.04
```

The `linux-libc-dev` should stay this version. It is not upgraded in 16.04.2.

That will install `linux-tools` packages that should match the running kernel version.

Also you can remove `linux-image`, `linux-headers` and `linux-tools` packages of the 4.4 version using e.g. synaptic if you are sure you won't use those kernels.

Comment: Trying to remove `linux-tools-common` removes the newly installed 4.8 `linux-tools` for some reason. Probably the `linux-tools-common` must stay?

Comment: `linux-tools-common` should stay.