# What is the safest way of upgrading the HWE stack?

Tags: apt, upgrade

Reading [the 1404_HWE_EOL wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL), it says

> 2. Manually installing the Ubuntu HWE packages (e.g. `.*-lts-wily`)

However, it also says

> To determine which packages to upgrade use:
>
> ```
> hwe-support-status --show-replacements
> ```

Which command would be the safer way of updating the HWE stack?

```
sudo apt-get install .*-lts-xenial`
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install $(hwe-support-status --show-replacements)
```

The former is over three times the size of the latter and includes fewer packages.

Comment: From my experience(http://askubuntu.com/questions/887682/low-graphics-mode-after-16-04-2-hwe-upgrade/887696#887696), I will suggest you to first change your graphics driver to Nouveau. Then perform the kernel update. Then after rebooting, do the xserver update. Then reboot. If everything runs fine, remove all the unnecessary old packages. This will also be of help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/888614/removing-left-over-kernel-packages-from-previous-kernel-after-hwe-upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Kernel/LTS Enablement site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), the proper command to run for 14.04 would be:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

Hope this helps!